# How to efficiently implement wildcard (.) in DFA

Tags: regex, algorithm, compiler-construction, wildcard, dfa

I've implemented an algorithm that converts a regex directly to a DFA. I was implementing wildcard in it as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61810683/implementing-wildcard-in-thompson-nfa?noredirect=1#comment109345568_61810683) mentioned I should. The problem is, it takes a *lot* of time to do `(a.*z)#` (let alone `(a.+z)#` which takes so long I have to kill the program). When I profiled the code I found that the place it took so long was not calculating the fistpos/lastpos/nullable/followpos; rather it was putting them together into the DFA. Upon further inspection in that function, I found that the part that calculated the states that a DFA state would be composed of took the bulk of the time. Here is the piece of code that took a long time:

```
composition = set()
for i in current_state.composition:
    # 'basic_nodes' maps the position of the leaf node to the leaf node
    # basic nodes looks like '{0: LeafNode("a"), 1: LeafNode("b"), 2: LeafNode("c"), ...}'
    for x in basic_nodes[i].followpos:
        if basic_nodes[i].value == letter:
            composition.add(x)
```

To give you a perspective, on constructing the second state, `current_state.composition` is ~255 elements long, and the followpos of most nodes is ~255 elements long. This is due to the fact that the wildcard operator creates 255 basic nodes, and adds them into its firstpos & followpos (just as if it were a bunch of alternates). The algorithm I am following is **Algorithm 3.6** in the Dragon Book (which I feel is an efficient algorithm). The problem (I believe) is the wildcard implementation because it adds 255 nodes spontaneously, and (I think) makes **Algorithm 3.6** slower. Is there a better wildcard implementation, or something else I could do to speed up my code?

Comment: Use character classes?

Comment: THe 2nd edition of the Dragon Book I have doesn't have an Algorithm 3.6. Which algorithm is it?

Comment: @rici -- Sorry for the late reply; I took a look in the pdf of the 2nd edition; It is **Algorithm 3.36** on page 179.

Comment: @rici -- Also: how would character classes be implemented differently? Won't character classes be implemented as something like `[a-z]` becomes `(a|b|c|d|e|f|...)`?

Comment: Usually they are bitmasks. There is just one transition entry for a CC

Comment: @rici -- I apologize for the late reply, but how would that work in a DFA?

Comment: let me see if I can throw some code together.

Comment: There's something really wierd about `for x in basic_nodes[i].followpos: if basic_nodes[i].value == letter: composition.add(x)`. The condition has nothing to do with the iteration variable (`x`); the condition will be the same boolean value for every iteration. So you don't need a loop at all; you could just write `if basic_nodes[i].value == letter: composition |= basic_nodes[i].followpos`. (There's an implicit loop in set operation, of course, but it will be a lot faster than your code.) But is that really what you mean to do?

Comment: Ah, silly me :)

Comment: The wildcard operator shouldn't need to create 255 different nodes. It should need to create one node and 255 different transitions